# Разделение текста на слова по заданным разделителям

Tags: c#

Всем привет, есть задача, разделить текст на предложения, а их на слова и потом преобразовать всё в нижний регистр. И все условия вроде выполнены, но когда посылаешь текст с ковычками, например ""test", то задача не отрабатывает, хоть ковычки и перечислены в разделителях. Можете подсказать в чём причина ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TextAnalysis
{
    static class SentencesParserTask
    {
        public static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
        {
            var separ = new[] { '.', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')' };
            var stringList = new List<string>();
            var sentencesList = new List<List<string>>();
            string[] sentences = text.Split(separ);
            stringList = sentences.ToList();
            var wordsList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in stringList)
            {
                //String pattern = @"([\d,]+)(\s*)(\r\n(\w+))";
                wordsList = (item.Split(new[] {' ', ',', '\t','\r','\n', '^','#','*','@','$','%','&','+','-','/', '1', '=', '\"'}).Where(x=>Check(x)).ToList());
                //wordsList = Regex.Split(item, pattern).Where(x => Check(x)).ToList();
                List<string> lowerCase = wordsList.Select(d => d.ToLower()).ToList();
                if (!(lowerCase.Count() == 0) ){

                    sentencesList.Add(lowerCase);
                }
            }

            return sentencesList;
        }

        private static bool Check(string x)
        {
            return x.Length > 0 && x.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).Count() > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот так все работает:
string text=" english words  \"test\"";
var result = SentencesParserTask.ParseSentences(text);